# Doubled page scroll by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
   scroll+=100;
   $(window).scrollTop(scroll); //*
})
```

But this code scroll the window with a loop to the bottom. how to make something like throttle in order to avoid the recursion ?

The goal: i have the 404 page and iframe with index page below of 404. and when user try to scroll 404 page - index pages scroll to top with doubled speed

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? What effect?

Comment: i have the 404 page and iframe with index page below of 404. and when user try to scroll 404 page - index pages scroll to top with doubled speed

Comment: Just for me to understand  when the user scrolls on the upper part of your page, you want him to quickly get to the index frame top, right?

Comment: ekeren, yes, index page without redirect )

Answer (score 0):

To Solve your issue I took a slightly different approach, upon scroll I am scrolling to the Index location only once.

```
var $window = $(window);
var indexLocation = 505;  
$window.one("scroll", function(e){
    if ($window.scrollTop() < indexLocation){
        $("body").animate({scrollTop: indexLocation});
    }
});
```

Also you can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/jsJJK/1/

Comment: made by -200px to div.height() when scroll event is coming

Comment: @user2560165 - what do you mean?